# Cakephp counterCache multiple counterScope - Logical issue

Tags: php, cakephp, counter-cache, performancecounter

Problem:

I have two models: Dealer, Testdrive (Testdrive belongs to Dealer through dealer_id). I want to show real time statistics about the dealers: total (Testdrive.active = 1), processed (Testdrive.active = 1 && Testdrive.processed = 1) ...

I have approx 100 dealers and 10000 testdrives. The count based sql takes about 10 sec (inefficient). Now i have a cronjob that runs every hour but I don't have real time stats.

I tried something like this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Dealer' => array(
        'className' => 'Dealer',
        'foreignKey' => 'dealer_id',
        'counterCache' => 'active',
        'counterScope' => array('Testdrive.active' => 1),
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Dealer' => array(
        'className' => 'Dealer',
        'foreignKey' => 'dealer_id',
        'counterCache' => 'processed',
        'counterScope' => array('Testdrive.active' => 1, 'Testdrive.processed' => 1),
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

... but i overwritten the belongsTo => 'Dealear' value.

Can I have an array of counterCache with an array of counterScope?

```
 var $belongsTo = array(
    'Dealer' => array(
        'className' => 'Dealer',
        'foreignKey' => 'dealer_id',
        'counterCache' => array('active', 'processed'),
        'counterScope' => array('active' => array('Testdrive.active' => 1), 'processed' => array('Testdrive.active' => 1, 'Testdrive.processed' => 1)),
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's (now) an example of this in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-countercache). Applied to the example in the question that would be:

```
class TestDrive extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Dealer' => array(
            'counterCache' => array(
                'active' => array(
                    'TestDrive.active' => 1
                ),
                'processed' => array(
                    'TestDrive.active' => 1, 
                    'TestDrive.processed' => 1
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Note there's no need to define keys with default values (`className`, `foreignKey` etc.).